# React PWA - enforce update on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, netlify

community,

I am doing "programmatic presentations" using React (CLI) and PWA (register()). Everything works just fine, but anytime some changes are made, the URL of the final app needs to be changed so all changes are loaded.

**The whole mechanism works like this:**

1. The final app is sent to Github,
2. this private repo is connected to Netlify,
3. Netlify generates a unique URL,
4. users visit this Netlify URL and hit "add to home screen" on iPad,
5. the whole app runs under the Safari engine.
6. If any change in the code is made, I have to change the link in Netlify and send this new link to a people.

The process mentioned above works just fine, but honestly, it would be nice **to have some kind of functionality** that allows request latest update on demand - let's say - on click of a button.

Is something like that possible?

Thank you for comments!

Kind Regards
Linc

Comment: Do you work with serviceworker in your pwa  app?

Comment: That is the question - What I actually do in React CLI - when I am done with all the work, I just change PWA function from "unregister()" to "register()". Everything is handled by React itself than. Ofc, I define manifest.json and so on, but all the PWA logic is done by React - so I was wondering if there is any inbuilt feature (like a function) I can call anytime update of assets is requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At **serviceWorker.js** file can find this code

```
if (config && config.onUpdate) {
    config.onUpdate(registration);
 }
```

So implement the  config.onUpdate funtion

Create a file **swConfig.js**

```
export default {
 onUpdate: registration => {
   registration.unregister().then(() => {
   window.location.reload()
  })
 },
}
```

At **index.js** send the implement function to serviceWorker

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import swConfig from './swConfig'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, 
document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.register(swConfig);
```

Check out this repo
https://github.com/wgod58/create_react_app_pwaupdate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the update with a button click, I did using the following snippet:

Note: If your app must work offline, you should add some extra logic to verify if the user has internet connection, as the following code would break the app if it's unable to fetch the service-worker.

```
import React from 'react';
function App(){
  const updateApp = () => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister().then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
    }}

  return(
    <div style={{margin:"auto"}}>
      <button onClick={updateApp}>
        Update App
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://gist.github.com/juliomilani/6492312d1eb657d06b13c9b87d5ad023